# Signature collection

Tags: pdf, signature

I'm looking for some software that will allow customers to electronically sign documents on my computer or mobile device (I'd be open to purchasing additional hardware if necessary).

I don't want to send the documents, I'll have them on my device - I just need to collect a customer's signature and put into the document - ideally legally binding.

Each document will follow a template, but be unique.

I'd like the process to be as simple as possible; open a document, click sign and sign.

**OS:** Windows 10 or iOS, although an Android device could be purchased if it's an ideal solution.
**Price:** Around £10/$15 per month.

Comment: One trick about legally binding might be that it's all tied to your device which limits provability / independence.  You can probably manage that if you take care of that shortly after the sign-process.  Just keep in mind the document would really benefit from some level of verification independent of your application / company.